# typo3 add content element to all pages that are direct child of a certain page using typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have defined a menu content element using typoscript:

```
lib.share = COA
lib.share {
    wrap = <div class="shareLinkBlock">|</div>
    1 = TEXT
    1.data = page : title
 ...
```

I would like to add this menu to colPos 2 of every page, that is direct child of a certain page.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A solution depends on the current realization of the page.

If you use only typoscript you can replace the colPos2 rendering with a COA where your typoscript is part one and the old rendering is a second part.
Using conditions can restrict the appearance to selected page trees.

In similar ways you can realize it with FLUID.
You can insert a fluid variable, filled with your typoscript in every page.
The restriction to special page trees can be realized with conditions in typoscript or in FLUID. Also you can use different page-layouts for pages with and without this menu.

another solution would be an additional backend column which gets inherited and where you fill in your menu for those pages where the menu starts being visible. (conditions like above)

---

EDIT:
if you want to enhance a given FLUID variable, defined in typoscript you can word with a `COA`:

```
:
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
   :
   variables {
      enhancedColumn = COA
      enhancedColumn {
         10 = ..old definition ...
      }
   }
}
:
// make sure you use the correct conditions:
[PIDinRootline = 10] 
...10.variables.20 < lib.footer
[global]
```

Comment: The page is realized with Fluid. Would it be possible to add some typoscript content to a page and get it rendered automatically?
I found something like that.
#[PIDinRootline = 10]
lib.footer = COA
lib.footer {
 10 = CONTENT
 10 {
 table = tt_content
  dontCheckPid = 1
  select.where = colPos = 2      
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.pidInList = 15  #footer page id
 }
}
#[end]

Otherwise, would it be possible to add an already rendered content element from an existing page to other pages?

Comment: there is not much difference between a declared FLUID variable and your typoscript which you might call from fluid with `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.footer" />` (make sure you have an empty `lib.footer` if you are in another rootline)

Comment: is there any chance to do this without modifying the fluid templates just using typoscript?

Comment: view my edit to the answer